# Azure Data Factory, transform without Data Flows possible?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using ADF to carry out a copy activity. I am copying from a source DB where a field property is set as a 0 to represent null. Is there a way I can transform the 0 to a False (string) before the copy takes place and my sink is updated?

Answer (score 0):

Core Azure Data Factory (ie not Mapping Data Flows) is not great on transformation so the usual approach would be to load the data 'as is' to a staging table and then transform it there (eg via a Stored Proc task).

If your source and target are the same database, then don't use a Copy task, just use a Stored Proc task to `INSERT` from one table to another.

As a last alternative, you could use the Copy activity with a Stored Proc option in the Sink.  The stored proc could then handle this transform easily, with the overhead of having to create the stored proc and supporting table type.

[image: ADF Copy activity with Stored Proc sink]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there no way to add an additional column at the Source and create a dynamic expression? This would almost be like a derived column.

Comment: You can add additional columns but you can’t do any transform on them directly in the pipeline.  Use Mapping Data Flows if you want a low-code approach, otherwise use one of the options above.